# What does it mean to put a 0 and a . before %

Tags: c, scanf

I came across this code

```
scanf("0.%[0-9]...\n", &x);
```

Why are we using 0. Before %?

Comment: So this applies to whatever we write before %?  E.g if we put ```x``` in place of ``` 0 .``` , would that mean it will scan only elements which start with ```x```?

Comment: Okh got it. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the code and added few more questions related to it.

Answer (score 2):

The regular character(that is not part of conversion) you put in scanf, should be entered as it is ordered while supplying input, like:

```
scanf("<-%c", c); // Need to suply <- and then a character.
```

Otherwise it will fail to take input.